# I can not reload jQuery DataTable ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have jQuery DataTable

```
function loadTable() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "searching": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/updateWithParams",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function (d) {
                    return $('#formFilter').serializeArray();
                }
            },
............
}
```

and call it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        loadTable();
    });
```

But after loading I can call this method on button(change form gata and reload table) but I get error - can not reanitialise dataTable.....
How can I reload datatable?

Edit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//        connect();
        setDatesFilters();
        loadTable();
    });

    function setDatesFilters() {
        var day = start.getDate();
        var month = start.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = start.getFullYear();
        var str = day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
        $('#startDateFilter').val(str.concat(" 00:00"));
        $('#endDateFilter').val(str.concat(" 23:59"));
    }
    var table;
    function reload() {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }
    function loadTable() {
        table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "searching": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/updateWithParams",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function (d) {
                    return $('#formFilter').serializeArray();
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "name"},
                {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": "status",
                    "render": function (data, type, full) {
                        if (data == 0) return "<p> Новая </p>";
                        if (data == 1 || data == 2) return "<p> Выполняется </p>";
                        if (data == 3) return "<p> Выполнено </p>";
                        if (data == 4) return "<p> Отменено </p>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "dateCreated",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        var dateStart = new Date(data);
                        var day = dateStart.getDate();
                        var month = dateStart.getMonth() + 1;
                        var year = dateStart.getFullYear();
                        return day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
                    }
                },
                {"data": "userName"},
                {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, full) {
                        if (data.status == '0') {
                            return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Запустить</button>";
                        }
                        if (data.status == '1' || data.status == '2') {
                            return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Остановить</button>";
                        }
                        if (data.status == '3') {
                            return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Скачать</button>";
                        }
                        if (data.status == '4') {
                            return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Отменено</button>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
            var id = table.cell(this).data().id;
            var status = table.cell(this).data().status;
            console.log("id: " + id + " status: " + status);
            if (status == '0') startResolution(id);
            if (status == '1' || status == '2') stopResolution(id);
            if (status == '3') downloadResolution(id);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to reload the datatable?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: try `$('#example').DataTable().api().ajax.reload();` or  `$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: @Punit Gajjar Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).api is not a function
    at reload (http://localhost:1239/:396:35)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://localhost:1239/:72:82)

Comment: @user5620472 , Can you make your code live ? or any fiddle for the same ?

Comment: No I can not this

Answer (score 0):

If data in server-side has been updated and you want to manually update in the front-end:

[ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

> In an environment where the data shown in the table can be updated at
>   the server-side, it is often useful to be able to reload the table,
>   showing the latest data. This method provides exactly that ability,
>   making an Ajax request to the already defined URL (use ajax.url() if
>   you need to alter the URL).

The [fnReloadAjax](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax) plugin also works the same but is deprecated as of DataTables 1.10 and up.

i.e:

```
var table = null;

function loadTable() {
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "searching": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/updateWithParams",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function (d) {
                return $('#formFilter').serializeArray();
            }
        },
............
}

function reloadTable(){
    table.ajax.reload(); 
    // or 
    // table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
}
```

Comment: I want pass form. I change form filter data and press show button where I call this method - reload table with new data

Comment: I add function reload() {
        table.ajax.reload();
    } but table not update on client side

Comment: I have updated my answer. Make sure `table` is a reference to the datatable.

Comment: I do it - function reload() {
        table.ajax.reload();
    } not helped

Comment: table.ajax.reload( null, false ) - I do it too. I can read documentation too

Comment: Also please add details of what has not helped does the problem or previous error still exists?

Comment: I see "Processing..." in center of table and table not reload

Comment: Could you check the console for errors? It might be that you have a bug in javascript or the their is a problem in the back-end.

Comment: Also, take note that the variable `table` must be accessible by both the 2 functions. Also don't declare it in either of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to refresh the data table after applying search filters:

```
$('#example').DataTable().draw();
```

Also calling that method I believe will reload the current page even if no search filters have been changed.

Comment: It is not helped. ajax call controller mrthod and controller method return data but on client side table not refresh

Comment: Just throwing this out there.  Was the data returned different than the currently displayed data?  Just trying to rule out the easy stuff.

Comment: I do not quite understand you. sorry for my English)

Comment: sorry.  Was the data returned from the controller method after the "draw" different than the data the was currently shown in the table?

Comment: Yes controller to return the data correctly and data is different

Comment: @user5620472  Drats.  Any chance you could expose a sample page that shows the issue with fake data?

Comment: I fine error. public class ResolutionsTable {
//    private String draw;
    private String recordsTotal;
    private String recordsFiltered;
    private List<ResolutionDto> data;
} I comment this field draw. But I not understand what means this field

Comment: That looks like a serverside error.  If you can update your question with your serverside code and the line that you commented out that would help us help you.